# Kafka cluster zookeeper failure handling

Tags: java, message-queue, apache-kafka, producer-consumer, kafka-producer-api

I am going to implement a kafka cluster consisting of 3 machines, one for zookeeper and other 2 as brokers. I have about 6 consumer machines and about hundred producers.

Now if one of the broker fails data loss is avoided thanks to replication feature. But what if zookeeper fails and the same machine cannot be started? I have several questions:

1. I noticed that even after zookeeper failure producers continued to push messages in designated broker. But they could no longer be retrieved by consumers. Because Consumers got unregistered. So in this case is data lost permanently?
2. How to change zookeeper ip in broker config in run time? Will they have to be shutdown to change zookeeper ip?
3. Even if new zookeeper machine is somehow brought into the cluster previous would the previous data be lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running only one instance of Zookeeper is not fault-tolerant and the behavior cannot be predicted. According to [HBase reference](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#zookeeper), you should setup an ensemble with at least 3 servers.

Have a look at the official documentation page: [Zookeeper clustered setup](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup).

Comment: so suppose in the setup mentioned above I also add 2 more zookeeper machines and if one of them fails then any one of remaining two can be connected? Will they have all the up-to-date data?

Comment: If you add two more machines, then only one can fail. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228227/what-does-2n-1-quorum-mean Yes, data will be in sync, because these machines are replicated.

Comment: on development environment I took two machines and added this config in each machine's zookeeper.config file `initLimit=5 syncLimit=2 server.1=x.x.x.x:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2888:3888` Server.2 being the server from which I am about to start zookeeper. So when I hit the startup script, I get error that server.1 with x.x.x.x:3888 cannot be connected.

Comment: Well, have you tried to debug first? e.g., telnet x.x.x.x 3888 ?

Comment: Ya sorry, I didn't mention everything in previous comment. This is the very thing  I am surprised about. port 3888 is not being run by any process on either machines. So how are they supposed to connect to that port? Do I have to run anything prior to starting zookeeper server?

Comment: I have just noticed that you don't have a clientPort specified. Have you tried following a tutorial like http://myjeeva.com/zookeeper-cluster-setup.html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93481/discussion-between-shades88-and-markon).

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned client port in config. Here's entire config
`dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0

initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=x.x.x.x:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2888:3888`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you pointed me in right direction. I was using zookeeper utility provided by kafka but one cannot create zookeeper cluster using that. That's why I was facing all above problems. I downloaded zookeeper separately started 3 instances, now everything works find

Comment: Great! I am glad it helped :)